# How to get the list of open windows on MacOS in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

Actually I'm trying to get the list of ALL open windows as next:

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly)
let windowsListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
let infoList = windowsListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]
```

but the problem here is that I'm getting also `Dock` or `Window Server`, `SystemUIServer` or widgets on the status bar. How can I improve my code to get avoid from those elements and to get only windows' list, as `Xcode`, `Finder`, etc.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that all visible windows have the value `0` for key `kCGWindowLayer`

```
import Cocoa

let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly)
let windowsListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
let infoList = windowsListInfo as! [[String:Any]]
let visibleWindows = infoList.filter{ $0["kCGWindowLayer"] as! Int == 0 }

print(visibleWindows)
```

Comment: This only returns the windows of the current active space.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static func visibleWindows() -> [NSWindow]
{
    return NSApplication.shared.windows.filter { $0.isVisible }
}
```

Comment: This only returns the windows of the current app.